# Show table if a SPAN exists within the first TD

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write in either jQuery or Javascript a way of hiding a table if it doesnt contain a specific span:

E.g.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="titletext">
      <span id="userID">009002</span>
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

So, as a poor psuedo code:

```
if (td.titletext child has #userID) {
  //do nothing
} else {
  td.titletext = Display: none;
}
```

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest would be:

```
if ($("td.titletext > #userId").length == 0) {
    $("td.titletext").hide();
}
```

However, the question is not exactly clear: you mention hiding the table, while the pseudocode says "hiding the `<td>`". Here's a "better" way of doing it:

```
var td = $("td.titletext");
if (td.children("#userId").length == 0) {
    // To hide the td:
    td.hide();

    // OR, to hide the table:
    td.closest('table').hide();
}
```

Comment: @redsquare: It's either `== 0` or `!` in front. I find the former more readable because you don't have to mentally do a type conversion. Readable is good.

Comment: if ( $("td.titletext > #userId").length ) will do since it returns a bool (0 or > 0)

Comment: @redsquare: If you mean that as in "not using `children`", then yes it will do for the test (in fact my original answer was like that). But if there are no children, it's easier and less error-prone to find the appropriate ancestor to hide with this code.

Comment: no I meant the '== 0' part, you do not need == 0 when testing if something is zero or not

Comment: @redsquare: Then I already told you why I prefer it this way. It's a matter of style, if you or anyone else prefers it without the `== 0` then that's also just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution w/ one selection made:

```
if (!(target = $('td.titletext > #userID')).length)
     target.parent().hide();
```